# Using Jooq to set a Character Array instead of String

Tags: java, arrays, string, jooq

I have a Jooq update query that is setting sensitive information. The sensitive information is a char[] and then I'm zeroing it out with Arrays.fill(characterArray, '0').

In order to set that value via Jooq, I have to transform that character array into a String which would defeat the purpose of the character array in the first place, because it would then create an immutable String in memory, where I would be at the mercy of Garbage Collection.

Is there a way for Jooq to set that value as a character array without converting it to a String first?

Comment: Just to get this right, you have something like a global variable that is of type `char[]`, in which you put at some given point, the sensitive information and you want jOOQ to read that information in the right moment and send it to the JDBC driver? How is the `char[]` going to be more secure than the string?

Comment: So I receive the data as type char[], which is then zeroed out after it's been set in the database. So it's only secure within the memory of the service (loosely, just a shortened window of opportunity). I know it's a drop in a bucket, and it's just as insecure in other areas, but every little bit helps. I was just asking because I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the zeroing out isn't really relevant to jOOQ, you're just giving this as some additional contextual information. Essentially, you want to bind a `char[]` to a `VARCHAR` column in your database, right?

Comment: Yes correct. Sorry, my explanations never really go as I originally envision them. :)

Comment: Yeah, asking a good question takes practice :) But that's what this platform is here for. Ask more questions and it'll get better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate approach here would be to create a [data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) for your `VARCHAR` column (which jOOQ treats as `String`) and your "user-defined type" `char[]`. The implementation would be along the lines of:

```java
public class CharArrayBinding implements Binding<String, char[]> {
    //                                           ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
    // JDBC / database type ------------------------+       |
    // user facing type     --------------------------------+

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<char[]> ctx) {
        ctx.statement().setCharacterStream(
            ctx.index(), 
            new java.io.CharArrayReader(ctx.value())
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

[That binding could then be associated with your relevant columns by the code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/).

Now, there are more methods to implement, but the above already shows the idea of how you could proceed here.

#### Some notes:

I don't fully understand your requirement, so my choice of `CharArrayReader` might still be inappropriate for your needs. Also, there is no guarantee that your JDBC driver might not perhaps perform some additional allocation either, which may or may not affect your requirements. I would personally prefer using encryption for these purposes, but again, maybe that doesn't suit your needs.

Nevertheless, by using a data type binding, you can override jOOQ's internals and there will not be any `String` allocation on your bind variable, performed by jOOQ.